# Navigator issue in App.js file -- React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When i am trying to configure components with AppNavigator getting parsing error semicolon missing.

React Native Navigation-V3.11.1

But i have checked, i did everything correct as per my vision.

Please give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance..!

[image]

Comment: add code snippets instead of images

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `. jshintrc` in the root and write the code below in it:

```js
"asi" : true
```